# Internet Explorer JQuery Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, error-handling

I am using JQuery min 1.4.2. I have a function which iterates through a few tables and adds a class with a number attached:

```
$("#reportArea table", this).each(function(i){
$(this).addClass("table-" + i);
});
```

For some reason this throws an error in IE 8 and IE9, however, in Firefox and Chrome when I open console, I do not see any errors. The error in IE is:

```
Message: Invalid argument.
Line: 48
Char: 1
Code: 0
URI: /js/jquery-min.js
```

If I look at line 48 in the IE debugger, I see this:

```
a[b]=d}if(c.nodeName(a,"form")&&a.getAttributeNode(b))return a.getAttributeNode(b).nodeValue; etc..
```

I also tried rephrasing my code to this but still get the same error:

```
$('#reportArea table:eq(0)').addClass('table-0');
$('#reportArea table:eq(1)').addClass('table-1');
```

The odd part is that the class still gets added to the tables in IE.

Note, I would add the classes manually but it's a JSP Report page and I don't have access to the specific template that controls this page.

Comment: Have you tried isolating this error by - just for this test case - using the latest jquery version?

Comment: Something else in your code is probably going south. Simple test case works (jQuery 1.4.4 so small chance a point release fixed something). Tested in IE9 - http://jsfiddle.net/gjbzZ/1/

Comment: yes I think the problem is somewhere else.  Remove that line and see if the problem stops happening

Comment: your error does not help.. you are showing the error of the minified code and n lines might be combined into 1.. use the non-minified version and then post the exact error.. also a screenshot of the callstack would help.. use IE debugger if necessary

Comment: I am geussing the error is in some other part, but yea the callstack should help

Comment: For debugging you really should use a non-minified version of jQuery

Comment: Ok it looks like JQuery 1.4.4 non minified solved the issue so it seems you all had generally the same idea. If someone wants to add this as an answer, I will be happy to award points. This is good to know for future debugging. thanks!

Answer (score -1):

```
$("#reportArea table", this).each(...
                       ^^^^
```

What is `this` in here? It should be a [DOM context](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1). I don't think you need it for your selector as ids are (should be) unique. If you're not calling that function inside a specific function, the [`this` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) might reference the global object and therefore cause the error.

Comment: in the second part he trys the simple jquery it still fails and it is looping through the foreach loop and thats why his classes are getting added.

Comment: Should actually be `$(this).find('#reportArea table').each(...`